# How did "Is the C# Thread class (unofficially) obsolete?" make it past the "Not Constructive" gauntlet?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, not-constructive

While I was meandering about the Stack-o-sphere, I noticed this question hit the SuperCollider:

[Is the C# Thread class (unofficially) obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894821)

OK... So why does this question (as of this writing) get 38 upvotes, no close votes, no moderator flags, and one of Eric Lippert's legendary answers, when it is essentially an **"Is [insert arbitrary technology here] dead?"** question?

Help me understand this.

**UPDATE:** Title of SO question edited to more correctly reflect what it is asking.

Comment: Because circlejerk

Comment: @random Too much reddit, heh?

Comment: Is this the right time to reference that "badgers" site you like?

Comment: @jonsca: Yes, this is [absolutely the right time.](http://www.badgerbadgerbadger.com/)

Comment: If I flag it for "not being flagged yet" will you be happy?

Comment: @animuson: I read that as *"You're being ridiculous."*

Comment: Because the *question body* was constructive, objectively answerable, and in reference to a real programming problem. Not everyone is good at writing titles. I see absolutely nothing with questions like this, and I should hope that our community standards are not so completely inflexible and poorly conceived that we would close useful, quality questions like that one without giving it a second thought. I fear that that is, however, *not* the case, as since you've brought it to Meta's attention, it has received 4 close votes. You can expect a flag to re-open if that 5th one gets cast.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm like that.  I look at a question title and I assume that it correctly represents the actual question being asked.  Alas, so few of us know how to write good titles.

Comment: @TheEstablishment - Now closed...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894821/are-there-any-cases-when-its-necessary-or-useful-to-use-a-plain-old-thread-obje/9894905#9894905):

> But that's not really your question; your question is
>
> > are there any cases when it's necessary or useful to use a plain old Thread object instead of one of the above constructs?
>
> ...

In other words, the asker wasn't really asking what it appears he's asking. "Is *X* dead?" and "Why don't more folks use *X*?" are two common discussion patterns that *do* deserve to get shut down - or edited into a more useful form. In this case, the top answers skipped the actual editing step and just answered the constructive form of the question.

You could edit it without invalidating them and avoid a potential broken window...

Comment: Good idea.  Done.