# Was it OK to reject this tag wiki edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

The [broken-windows](/questions/tagged/broken-windows) tag wiki excerpt says:

> **inappropriate questions used to** justify posting of new similar questions...

But in *Tags* screen it is cut to

> justify posting of new similar questions...

Based on a similar change done [per discussion at WP Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/424/168), I suggested the edit for the excerpt intending to show a more complete text: ***these are** inappropriate questions used to justify posting of...*.

My edit [has been rejected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6604) as too minor. Is that OK?

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/65W4b.png]

Comment: Why does this tag even exist? We already have an [meta-tag:so-history] tag which pretty much covers this.

Comment: @animuson see [What is the meaning of the “broken-windows” tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128094/165773) As for [meta-tag:so-history], well "questions about the past" to me sound like a different matter than ["why can't I ask X when Y exists"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/broken-windows/info)

Comment: I'm aware of what it means, but I still feel like the tag covers this. - *Use this tag for questions about the past of Stack Exchange. What was done back in the day, why they did it, and why we \*don't\* do it now.* - I really don't see why we need two separate tags for this, when both of them are barely used. Also, a lot of people *won't* know what broken windows means. History is a much more clear term.

Comment: @animuson I see, interesting. You certaily have a point here

Comment: Also, I'm not a fan of tags specifically for "these questions are inappropriate." If they're not appropriate, delete them. The ones that *are* appropriate should be in an appropriate category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rejected it because adding just two words is in my opinion too minor. And on meta, a single reject vote is enough.

If you have special reasons (like the one you mentioned in the post), please add it in the edit reasons, to help deciding. Be sure to focus on the fact you know it is a minor edit, but you have a perfect justification for it.

In order to decide if the reject was ok or not, I'm afraid we need a better (more concrete) definition of too minor. Which should be different for tag edits than for post edits.

Comment: the edit reason was written as **"workaround for incorrectly cut excerpt display bug recently reported at WP Meta: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/424/168"** - what else would you suggest to add?

Comment: Something like:  Minor edit justified because else the excerpt is cut in a way the meaning becomes different.  (Just be sure you are aware it is a minor edit and you have a justification)

Comment: OK [suggested edit has been re-submitted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/6606 "re-submitted") with edit reason like you describe and approved

Comment: And it is already accepted.  Problem solved. ;-).

Answer (score 4):

I think it is better when the tag excerpt is written as a sentence, and I also prefer when the excerpt is not truncated in the page showing all the existing tags.

It is true that truncating the tag excerpt in that page doesn't probably make sense, as the tag excerpts are not truncated in the tag popup that is visible in the same page. Still, I don't think the edit is just a workaround for a "bug" in the software; it is a way to show the full tag excerpt, and avoid new users get confused from the truncated description.

I agree, "minor edit" is someway subjective; while we probably agree that changing a single character is too minor, the upper limit for "minor edit" is probably fuzzy. To me, it is not too minor if it is helpful, and there isn't anything else that needs to be changed.