# A rejected suggested-edit was later applied by a different user - impact on the original editor?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I made a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1140885) which was rejected with the reason **too minor edit**. My original idea was to just add the word "into" in the post (which I thought did make the question more readable), but when I tried to submit it I got the "Edits must be at least 6 characters" error so I made a couple other minor but appropriate changes and submitted it.  It was eventually rejected.  Later the same change was made in [another edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13753441/revisions), this time by someone who has the edit privileges who could add a shorter edit.

I understand a "too minor edit" rejection can be subjective (I am not complaining although I am not too happy about it), but I was wondering if there is a way for the original suggested edit owner to not accumulate another rejected edit into his/her account in such a situation.

Comment: The second, small edit was made by the original author of the question.

Comment: A rejected edit here or there is not a big deal. Just learn from it, so you don't accumulate a large number of them.

Comment: comment of your suggested edit is: "improved formatting", which, well, not quite fairly reflects what you did does it? for better approval rate, take care of comments **properly reflecting edit reasons** ([BTDTGTTS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146346/was-it-ok-to-reject-this-tag-wiki-edit#comment419038_146348 "see here: 'suggested edit has been re-submitted with edit reason like you describe and approved'"))

Comment: @gnat: you are right, my edit comment doesn't correctly reflect what I actually changed; I will be more careful the next time. Thanks for bringing that up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.  The change you mentioned was actually from the same user who posted the original question, so that user has the right to change/edit regardless of editing.  Perhaps he or she re-read the question and saw it was missing a critical word?  There isn't really a way (or, to be honest, much of a need) for a system to track that your peer-reviewed edit was rejected, but the same changes were later implemented.  It's the same thing with flags that are disputed or dismissed, but the action expected by the flagger was still taken.

Simply put, grin and bear it =)

Comment: I didn't realize it was changed by the OP of the question - thanks for pointing that out. It was an error on my part too, I didn't add the appropriate comment for the edit that truly reflects what I did. I like the way you put it - "grin and bear it".

Answer (score 2):

No.  Your suggestion was "too minor" and as such was appropriately rejected.  You *should* have a rejection on your record for that reason.

There have been *many* posts/debates on meta about both definitions of, and arguments in favor of or opposition to rejections as "too minor", so I will avoid re-creating another one and just summarize a few main points.

When suggesting edits you should make an effort to fix *all* of the problems you can find in the post.  You should not just fix one or two things and move on.  One main reason is that suggested edits need to be reviewed.  You are adding additional effort for reviewers every time you suggest something, and their time and effort comes at a cost.  That time and effort would be much better spent on substantial edits that significantly improve the post rather than very minor edits.

Also note that while a suggested edit is under review the post is locked; it can't be edited by other users until the suggested edit is approved or rejected.

Those problems, as well as some of the lesser reasons I haven't mentioned, don't apply at all, or as much, to users with full edit privileges.  They don't need to consume the time and effort of other reviewers to make an edit, so it's not nearly as important for them to avoid making smaller edits.  (Users with full edit privileges should still avoid making minor edits as much as possible, even though there is no system in place to stop them.)

If you would like to help out the site by editing posts that's *great*, by all means keep it up, but if you would like to do so you should make an effort to provide substantial edits to posts.  It will *greatly* improve the value that you're adding to the site, even if the total number of edits that you can make is lower.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, and the insight about the time and effort it takes for the reviewers.