# Is it OK to suggest an edit for the same tag wiki more than once?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, rollbacks

Since I don't have 20k rep, I can only suggest edits for tag wikis. On several occasions, after submitting the suggested edit I discovered I made a minor error.

Had my suggestion been rejected, I would gladly submit a fixed suggested edit. However, my edit was approved and I got the +2 rep. Is it OK for me to submit a fix to my edit (which would be very minor)? Somehow it doesn't feel right that I would get more rep (assuming the next edit would be approved) due to my original mistake. My other options are either to wait till I get to 20k rep (at my current rate that might happen around the end of 2014) or to ask a 20k user to fix my error.

Is it possible for me to rollback the edit?
If it's not possible once it is approved, can I rollback a suggested edit that hasn't been approved yet? Can I modify a suggested edit that hasn't been approved yet?

Comment: No. No. No and no.

Comment: @ColeJohnson In that case, what would you do?

Comment: Generally, [why not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/143821/revisions "an example: revisions 2 and 5 are mine")? Though, since you mention that the fix is _minor_, you better put some extra effort into [explaining to reviewers why you believe such a minor change is justified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146346/was-it-ok-to-reject-this-tag-wiki-edit#comment419037_146348 "example: 'Just be sure you are aware it is a minor edit and you have a justification'")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that, as long as the edit is intended to improve the tag wiki, there's nothing wrong with suggesting it. Just add a note in the Edit Summary explaining that you're correcting an error in your previous edit.

If you deliberately split the edit into two parts to get more points, that would be a bad thing, but I take your word that that's not what you're doing (and if you were, you probably wouldn't ask about it here).

But if you find yourself doing this a lot, you might want to spend a little more time checking for errors before submitting the first edit.

> Is it possible for me to rollback the edit? If it's not possible once it is approved, can I rollback a suggested edit that hasn't been approved yet? Can I modify a suggested edit that hasn't been approved yet?

If the edit has been approved, all you can do is submit another edit. If the edit hasn't been seen by any reviewer yet, you can edit again, and your new suggestion will replace the old one. If the edit has been partially reviewed, you need to wait until the final reviewer comes along.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Hmm? How is "wouldn't be asking here" an improvement over "wouldn't ask about it here"?